# R - plotly/ggplot2 - Change dynamically color over grouped boxplots

Tags: r, plotly

I have a set of datas structured as follow :

```
names       data        behaviour   timeOrder
(str)       (float)     (str)       (int)

userName1   0.542       green       1
userName1   0.456       green       1
userName1   0.514       red         2
userName1   0.625       blue        3
userName2   0.465       blue        3
userName2   0.635       red         1
userName2   0.464       red         1
.....
```

each user has a data set among three conditions (behaviours b1/2/3) and those conditions happen in the experimentation in a different order (3,1,2 / 2,3,1 ....)

I'd like to represent sets of three data boxplots for each user, displayed in the order told by timeOrder, but colored by the behaviour it represents

(usernames in x axis, boxplot in y axis)

I managed to do that with barplots and means values as shown below but my method doesn't apply for sets of data

[same principle with barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQDqZ.png)

Is that something possible ? For the moment i achieved to print the three boxplots grouped with

```
  p <- plot_ly(usersDataFrames, x = ~userName, y = ~data, type = "box",color = ~behaviour) %>%
      layout(boxmode = "group")
```

but the colors aren't managed manually

any help is appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can get close to your desired output is using **facets** in `ggplot2` and transforming timeOrder into a factor, so its plotted in order.

With `scale_fill_manual()` you can define the colors for filling the boxplots to whatever you choose. In this case, red, green and blue.

The following will create a grid of facets, one for each user, in a single row.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(timeOrder), y = data, fill = behaviour)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(.~names) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it works great for the grid, but it doesn't take the colors I set, instead I get the default colors (that are also green blue red but in the RGB order), how may I change that ?

Comment: You can define the colors using `scale_fill_manual()` in ggplot2. I'll add it to the answer.